# Change field name in Kotlin runtime

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible to change field name in Kotlin runtime? I need change filed name in my json serializator for use fild with dots (for example: `"fields.field":"value"`)

Comment: What serialization framework are you using? Most frameworks allow specifying custom serialization keys to use instead of field names.

Comment: In our test automation framework we use serializator on base org.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What serializator are you using? In most cases it can be done using annotations. Using Moshi you can do it like that:

```
class SomeClass(
    @field:Json(name = "newPropertyName")
    var someProperty: String
)
```

Comment: In our test automation framework we use serializator on base org.json